# How to save android notifications and restore them on reboot

Tags: android, android-intent, service, notifications, statusbar

My problem is, that I get too many notifications on my Android device and often end up not having opened (read) all of them before the battery dies (shutdown). Obviously, those remaining notifications get lost in the process.

Is there a way to read (the whole) data of incoming notifications by use of a background service. Which can then use that data to resend (restore) those notifications at a later point in time.

The objective I´m aiming for is to have all notifications data captured and stored to file. On device startup the service should then send out all notifications based on the data from that file as notifications again.

If a (already saved) notification has already been clicked on, it´s entry should be removed from the file. Therefore, only remaining notifications before imminent shutdown should be left.

Answer (score 0):

You can read notifications of other apps, when they arrive, Follow this [link](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html) to read all notifications arrived using a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and then save them and then using a Service which starts in response to the BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION Intent. you can read all those saved notifications

Comment: I already have an application ready that runs a Notification Listener Service in background which captures all notifications. My problem is that I don´t think I can just send notifications again from those captured "StatusBarNotification" objects alone.